# Time Machine sparsebundle mounting problems

Tags: time-machine, macos, mount, sparsebundle

### Problem

I have a Time Machine backup which contains **a lot** of valuable information and I'm trying to access it. What's the problem? I'm trying to mount it and nothing<sup>1</sup> happens.

1. Nothing happens? So I tried to eject the network disk containing the sparsebundle and I got an error saying:

> "The disk backups couldn't be ejected because finder it using it"

What??? My guess is DiskImageMounter is mounting but is *ridiculously* slow?

### Notes / Updates

> Note: `installd` is eating up my CPU usage, is this in anyway related to DiskImageMounter
>
> Note 2: If I go to "Browse Other Backup Disks" it finds the sparsebundle but none of the backups show.
>
> Update: Seems like `mds` is going crazy on the backup drive. I'll try to disable spotlight and see what I can do

---

There must surely be a better way to browse a Time Machine backup on a network disk

If not, how can my problem be fixed?

Comment: If you reboot your system does the issue persist? For `installd` see [What is installd, and why is it eating my CPU?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87109/what-is-installd-and-why-is-it-eating-my-cpu)

Comment: @user3439894 yup of course. I know about `installd` but I just added it if it has anything to do with mounting the disk image

Comment: You didn't answer my question! So I'll ask it again. If you reboot your system does the issue persist?  As far as `installd` have you looked at Open Files and Ports for it in Activity Monitor to see if it shows anything pointing to the Time Machine sparse bundle?

Comment: @user3439894 yes I think `fsck_hfs` looks like it's something to do with mounting. It does persist if I restart. I'm not seeing an `Open Files and Ports` tab...

Comment: actually now I'm seeing a `diskimages-helper` which is accessing the disk images... It's been over 30 minutes and no mount so I'll see if anything happens

Comment: To see the Open Files and Ports tab, if it exists for a given process, just double-click the name of the process.

Comment: @user3439894 yeah. It only shows for some processes. Will this mount the *entire* backup sparsebundle to my computer? Currently over 3GB and rising amount of RAM has been allocated to the mounting processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's not Time Machine, or anything

It's *Spotlight*. How?

### Spotlight

Spotlight indexes *everything*. Even on an external disk. My backup .sparsebundle was **> 2 TB**. My computer can't handle this. Spotlight would index everything before it showed in finder.

### Debugging

First, to see *what* was using the disk. Run:

```
sudo lsof | grep /Volumes/<Volume Name>
```

I got something like:

```
diskimage 519           vihan    4r      mds
```

and about 4 of those. That meant Spotlight was going haywire.

### Disabling

Disabling spotlight is simple. **RUN THIS BEFORE TOUCHING THE .SPARSEBUNDLE**

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

That should disable Spotlight. Now you can double click the .sparsebundle and [continue as from this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205426/44905)

Comment: Newer versions of MacOS won't allow this - you'll see 'Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged' instead. [This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/) describes the workaround, which I haven't tried just yet, but I'm instead trying to disable my Time Machine drive from indexing (in System Prefs -> Spotlight -> Privacy)... and if that doesn't work I'm trying to copy the sparsebundle locally (although I suspect I won't have enough disk space for that!)

Comment: You can omit "-w" option so SIP will not complain.